# Does high-context manifest in Japanese grammar and syntax?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, japanese, multilingualism, anaphora, ellipsis

Supposedly being a high-context culture, do modern Japanese text genres also sport a higher prevalence of ellipsis?

Do Japanese texts, by and large, sport more *kinds* of high-context manifestations in the grammar they represent, or a higher prevalence of high-context, at the sentence or word level, than what many other languages do?